# Discriminacion de valores en un array con valores de otro array

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo un problema con laravel tengo dos arrays resultado de dos consultas en el controller tal que asi:

```php
//array de usuarios se llama $users
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1" // id
        [1]=> string(9) "carlos" // name
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2" // id
        [1]=> string(8) "javier" // name
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "3" // id
        [1]=> string(8) "jorge" // name
    }
}

//array de blogs se llama $blogs
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1" // id
        [1]=> string(9) "carlos" // bloger
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2" // id
        [1]=> string(8) "carlos" // bloger
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(1) "3" // id
        [1]=> string(8) "jorge" // bloger
    }
}
```

pues lo que quiero es discriminar los usuarios del array de usuarios si no tienen ninguna coincidencia en el array de blogs, o lo que es lo mismo quiero que el resultado sea un array con los usuarios que tienen algún blog subido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma puedes recorrer ambos `array` y almacenar los usuarios que tienen publicaciones en `$result`:

```
<?php
$result = [];
foreach ($blog as $post) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (!$found && $user[1] === $post[1]) {
            $result[] = $user;
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

He de reconocer que lo más óptimo sería trabajar `while`, pero esta opción te va ha ser de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias! en general se me da bien php pero en esta ocasión se me ha atragantado

Comment: No te preocupes, ¡estamos todos para preguntar, responder y aprender!